# When should a Spliterator stop splitting?

Tags: java, concurrency, parallel-processing, fork-join, spliterator

I understand that [there is overhead in setting up](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/StreamParallelGuidance.html) the processing of a parallel `Stream`, and that processing in a single thread is faster if there are few items or the processing of each item is fast.

But, is there a similar threshold for [`trySplit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#trySplit--), a point where decomposing a problem into smaller chunks is counterproductive? I'm thinking by analogy to a merge sort switching to insertion sort for the smallest chunks.

If so, does the threshold depend on the relative cost of `trySplit()` and [consuming](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#tryAdvance-java.util.function.Consumer-) an item in the course of `tryAdvance()`? Consider a split operation that's a lot more complicated than advancing an array index—splitting a lexically-ordered multiset permutation, for example. Is there a convention for letting clients specify the lower limit for a split when creating a parallel stream, depending on the complexity of their consumer? A heuristic the `Spliterator` can use to estimate the lower limit itself?

Or, alternatively, is it always safe to let the lower limit of a `Spliterator` be 1, and let the work-stealing algorithm take care of choosing whether to continue splitting or not?

Comment: "let the work-stealing algorithm take care of choosing whether to continue splitting or not" is generally the best policy.  If the action on each element is sufficiently expensive, then splitting all the way down may be the best policy, even if the split is somewhat expensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you have no idea how much work is done in the consumer passed to `tryAdvance` or `forEachRemaining`. Neither stream pipeline nor FJP knows this as it depends on user supplied code. It can be either much faster or much slower than the splitting procedure. For example, you may have two-elements input but the processing of each element takes one hour, so splitting this input is very reasonable.

I usually split the input as much as I can. There are three tricks which can be used to improve the splitting:

1. If it's hard to split evenly, but you can track (or at least roughly estimate) the size of each sub-part, feel free to split unevenly. The stream implementation will do more further splitting for the bigger part. Don't forget about `SIZED` and `SUBSIZED` characteristics.
2. Move the hard part of splitting to the next `tryAdvance`/`forEachRemaining` call. For example, suppose that you have a known number of permutations and in `trySplit` you are going to jump to other permutation. Something like this:

   ```
   public class MySpliterator implements Spliterator<String> {
       private long position;
       private String currentPermutation;
       private final long limit;

       MySpliterator(long position, long limit, String currentPermutation) {
           this.position = position;
           this.limit = limit;
           this.currentPermutation = currentPermutation;
       }

       @Override
       public Spliterator<String> trySplit() {
           if(limit - position <= 1)
               return null;
           long newPosition = (position+limit)>>>1;
           Spliterator<String> prefix = 
                    new MySpliterator(position, newPosition, currentPermutation);
           this.position = newPosition;
           this.currentPermutation = calculatePermutation(newPosition); // hard part
           return prefix;
       }

       ...
   }
   ```

   Move the hard part to the next `tryAdvance` call like this:

   ```
   @Override
   public Spliterator<String> trySplit() {
       if(limit - position <= 1)
           return null;
       long newPosition = (position+limit)>>>1;
       Spliterator<String> prefix = 
                new MySpliterator(position, newPosition, currentPermutation);
       this.position = newPosition;
       this.currentPermutation = null;
       return prefix;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super String> action) {
       if(currentPermutation == null)
           currentPermutation = calculatePermutation(position); // hard part
       ...
   }
   ```

   This way the hard part will also be executed in parallel with prefix processing.
3. If you have not so many elements left in current spliterator (for example, less than 10) and the split was requested, it's probably good just to advance to the half of your elements collecting them into array, then create an array-based spliterator for this prefix (similarly to how it's done in `AbstractSpliterator.trySplit()`). Here you control all the code, so you can measure in advance how normal `trySplit` is slower than `tryAdvance` and estimate the threshold when you should switch to array-based split.